# How to install ASP.NET 5 IIS Loader using nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, iis-express

I am trying to run a new asp.net5 project on IIS loader, but I can't get it to work.
The error message is:

> Could not find the Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop Nuget Package in your users packages folder.This NuGet package is required to run ASP.NET 5 web applications.

I have installed the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015 (as you can see in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRxxq.png)) and have installed the **Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS 1.0.0-beta7 (prerelease)** nuget package ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsMhR.png)).

What am I missing?

Comment: A similar issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/999202/unable-to-run-asp-net-vnext-project. What's your VS and Asp.Net 5 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net 5 is no longer supported and replaced by Asp.Net Core now. I recommend you to migrate your project to Asp.Net Core and then try again. You can follow this link to migrate your project: [Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/rc1-to-rtm).

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the missing package is Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop. But in your second screenshot, you are installing Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS package, which is not the missing package.

[image: Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS nuget packages]

Please install the Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop package with command "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop -Pre" in Package Manager Console.

In addition, please make sure your Visual Studio has enabled auto restore nuget packages through Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your original post to provide the detailed steps from how do you create you web site and install packages and how to run it? If possible, please share a problematic project here.